# cross reference in ASP.Net Syncfusion spreadsheet

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, syncfusion

Does ASP.NET MVC Spreadsheet control in 3rd party tool syncfusion support cross sheet reference? I've been trying to look if cross sheet reference is being supported but could not find any.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Syncfusion have provided the support for the cross sheet reference in ASP.NET MVC Spreadsheet.  Please refer the following Spreadsheet sample to demonstrate the cross sheet reference in formulas.

[JS Playground](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/bskoxoeg)

**Code Snippet :**

```
<div id="Spreadsheet"></div>                

<script type="text/javascript">
    var productData = [
            { Product: "Product1", Quantity: 10, Price: 10 },
            { Product: "Product2", Quantity: 12, Price: 20 }];

    $(function () {
        $("#Spreadsheet").ejSpreadsheet({
            //...
            sheetCount: 2,
            sheets: [
                { rangeSettings: [{ dataSource: productData, startCell: "A1", showHeader: true }] },
            ],
            loadComplete: "loadComplete"
        });
    });

    function loadComplete(args) {
        if(!this.isImport){

            this.gotoPage(2, false); //Make Sheet2 as active sheet.

            this.XLEdit.updateValue("A1", "=Sheet1!A1"); // Here "=Sheet1!A1" is Sheet1=>"A1" cell value reference and the value of A1 cell in Sheet1 is updated in Sheet2 "A1" cell.

            //...

            this.XLEdit.updateValue("B2", "=PRODUCT(Sheet1!B2,Sheet1!C2)");      

            //...
        }
    }

</script>
```

Also, please refer the online [MVC Spreadsheet hyperlink Sample](http://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/web/spreadsheet/hyperlinkcomment). In that, we have used the cross sheet reference for the hyperlinks which is placed under the `StockDetail` column.

Comment: Will the B2 cell in the above example change dynamically when i change the Sheet1 B2 and c2 cell value after importing a complex nested formula sheet?

Comment: Yes. In Syncfusion MVC Spreadsheet, the formula cells are refreshed automatically once the referenced cell values are changed. This will happen even after importing too. In the above example, the property `isImport` in `loadComplete` event is used to check whether the actions are need to be performed on importing or not. So that the code block inside the `loadComplete` is not execute after importing.